# Django error local variable 'item_id' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

i got everytime this error, i have no idea how to solve this problem. i'm sending item id with jquery to connect conversation object.

my view:

```
def chatpage(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    item_id = int(request.POST['item_id'])

    return JsonResponse({'status': 200})
    message_form = MessageForm(data=request.POST)

    if message_form.is_valid():
        new_message = message_form.save(commit=False)
        new_message.conversation_id = item_id
        new_message.agreement_delivery_time = 12
        new_message.save()
else:
    message_form = MessageForm()

conversation = Conversation.objects.get(id=item_id)
messages = conversation.message_set.all()

return render(request, 'templates/Chatapp/chat.html',
              {'message_form': message_form,
               'conversation': conversation,
               'messages': messages})
```

Comment: You only create an `item_id` when you receive a post. What do you do when you get a post

Comment: i want to get conversation object and all mesages related to this conversation object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and let me know if that's what you are looking for:

```
def chatpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_id = int(request.POST['item_id'])
        message_form = MessageForm(data=request.POST)
        if message_form.is_valid():
            new_message = message_form.save(commit=False)
            new_message.conversation_id = item_id
            new_message.agreement_delivery_time = 12
            new_message.save()
        conversation = Conversation.objects.get(id=item_id)
        messages = conversation.message_set.all()
    else:
        message_form = MessageForm() 
    return render(request, 'templates/Chatapp/chat.html', locals())
```

**You can access each variable through its name in your template.**